# ¿Es posible llamar el archivo php desde si mismo?

Tags: php

Para ser honesto estoy buscándole la vuelta "innecesariamente", pero me da curiosidad, recién estoy empezando con php y busqué pero no pude encontrarlo.

Uso el interprete para ejecutar un pequeño php que hice y la idea sería ejecutarse a si mismo en lugar de usar un bucle (ya que aún "no vimos eso").

Les pongo un código simple que representaría lo que quiero hacer:

numero.php

```
<?php
  echo "Ingrese un número de 1 a 10: ";
  $numero = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  if($numero < 1 || $numero > 10) {
    echo "Número incorrecto, ¿prueba otra vez? (S/N): ";
    $respuesta = strtoupper(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
    if($respuesta == "S") {

      llamar numero.php

    }
  }
  echo "\n";
?>
```

Probé usando shell_exec(), no da error, pero ya no responde nada.

Por las dudas, si tiene alguna diferencia, estoy usando Linux.

---

La sugerencia de Eduardo:

```
<?php

  include("./numero.php");

  echo "Ingrese un número de 1 a 10: ";
  $numero = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  if($numero < 1 || $numero > 10) {
    echo "Número incorrecto, ¿prueba otra vez? (S/N): ";
    $respuesta = strtoupper(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
    if($respuesta == "S") {
        numero();
    }
  }
  echo "\n";
?>
```

Al ejecutarlo con `php numero.php` no hace nada, teniendo que terminar la ejecución con <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y usando `header("Location: numero.php");` como sugirió Eduardo, no sabría cómo ejecutar `numero.php` desde el `if($respuesta == "S")`

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, pruebe ocupando "include". Aquí le dejo un ejemplo de este código:

```
<?php include ('../lugarDondeEste/numero.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Al agregarle la línea hace lo mismo que cuando se usa `shell_exec()`, o sea queda como ejecutando algo pero ya no responde.

Comment: Prueba hacer un header["Location: nombre del archivo.php"];

Comment: Con esto consigues hacer redireccionamientos. Te dejo el link del manual de php: http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Comment: @MarioGuiber No logro entender cómo funcionaría `header("/direccion/del/archivo/numero.php");` para hacer lo que digo. Le agregué la línea pero luego no sé como hacer para ejecutar nuevamente el archivo en la parte `if($respuesta == "S")`... probé llamarla como función y lógicamente dice que la función no está declarada.